# Other definition of matter density parameter

Tags: cosmology, definition, density

I am reading an article and the authors give this definition of the matter density parameter $\Omega_m$
$$\Omega_m=\frac{8\pi Ga^2}{3\mathcal{H^2}}\overline{\rho}=\frac{\mathcal{H}_0^2\Omega_{m0}}{a\mathcal{H}^2}$$
where $\Omega_{m0}=8\pi Ga_0^2\overline{\rho}_0/(3\mathcal{H}_0^2)$. Since the density scales as $\rho=\rho_0\left(a/a_0\right)^{-3}$, shouldn't I have another $a_0$ in the previous expression of $\Omega_m$?

Comment: Which article? Which page?

Comment: Sorry, "Relativistic perturbations in $\Lambda$CDM: Eulerian & Lagrangian approaches" by Villa and Rampf. Equation 5.6